# How to fix Expo Print.printToFileAsync(options) undefined is not an object error

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to use Expo's Print.printToFileAsync(options but I keep on getting [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_expoPrint.Print.printToFileAsync')].

I looked for a lot of solutions online but couldn't find a solution to this. I started using React Native libraries but as I searched, turns out I can only use Expo's library so I switched to Print.printToFileAsync().

## App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Print } from 'expo-print';

export default class App extends Component {

  async createPDF() {

    let filePath = await Print.printToFileAsync({
      html: "<h1>PDF TEST</h1>",
      width : 612,
      height : 792,
      base64 : false
    });

    alert('PDF Generated', filePath.uri);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.createPDF} style={styles.Main}>
          <Text>Create PDF</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Main : { marginTop : 100 }
});
```

## Package.JSON

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "expo-print": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-html-to-pdf": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-share": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

My end goal is to make a PDF file using HTML in my Expo project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Expo sdk33 requires the module to be installed and run directly.

```
expo install expo-print
```

**Modular Imports**

With SDK 33, **we’re deprecating imports of most modules from the `expo` package.** This means that in a future release, you won’t be able to write, for example, `import { FileSystem } from 'expo';`. Rather, you’ll need to install the individual packages for each module you use and import from them instead.

You can use the new `expo install` command to install modules; this command is a wrapper around `npm install/yarn add` that automatically installs a module version compatible with your SDK version. For example, for the `FileSystem` module, you would run `expo install expo-file-system` and then use `import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';`. This change paves the way for tree-shaking and smaller JavaScript bundles. It also makes moving between the managed and bare workflows simpler.

Imports from the `expo` package will continue to work in SDK 33 but will generate a warning in the console, and you’ll need to import from the individual packages to make the warning disappear. To make this change easier, we’re providing a [codemod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-codemod) that’ll automatically update all of your imports for you.

Home page with description of [SDK33](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v33-0-0-is-now-available-52d1c99dfe4c)

Answer (score 1):

Please use -
import * as Print from 'expo-print';

instead of -
import { Print } from 'expo-print';

Answer (score 0):

follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/71569236/14448694

import * as Print from "expo-print"; import { shareAsync } from "expo-sharing";