# Dynamic HTML table in React Native PDF

Tags: react-native

**`listData`** below is a dynamic array of data. I'm trying to print the data in to a PDF using `expo-print`.
How can I dynamically populate required number of table rows based on the array length and print each result in a seperate row?

```
"listdata": [
    "OAG0001",
    "RAA0012",
    "RAA0098",
    "RAB0023",
    "UAE0014"
  ]
```

What I've tried so far below obviously prints the total array in to a single table row.

```
const printLoadOutData = () => {
        setPrintLoadoutLoader(true);

        const dataLoadOutToprint = `
        <html>
        <header>
        </header>
        <title></title>
            <style>
                table, th, td {
                border:1px solid black;
                }
            </style>
        <body>
            <table >
                <tr>
                    <td>"${listData}"</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
        </html >`;

        Print.printAsync({
            html: dataLoadOutToprint,
            width: 3508,
            height: 2480,
            orientation: Print.Orientation.landscape
        })

            .then(() => {
                setPrintLoadoutLoader(false);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                setPrintLoadoutLoader(false);
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
const listdata = [
    "OAG0001",
    "RAA0012",
    "RAA0098",
    "RAB0023",
    "UAE0014"
  ];

const htmltable = () => {
   let t = '';
   for (let i in listdata) {
     const item = listdata[i];
     t = t +
      `<tr>
         <td>${item}</td>
       </tr>`
   }
   return t;
}
```

##### Html content be like:

```
const htmlContent =
`<html>
    <header></header>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        table, th, td {
           border:1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
       <table>
          ${htmltable()}
       </table>
    </body>
</html>`;
```

##### Print function:

```
const print = () => {
  Print.printAsync({
     html: htmlContent,
     width: 3508,
     height: 2480,
     orientation: Print.Orientation.landscape
  }).then(() => {
     setPrintLoadoutLoader(false);
  }).catch(() => {
     setPrintLoadoutLoader(false);
  })
}
```

Comment: looping through data it is! I'm not entirely sure of what the newAr const does though.

Comment: Post updated!, removed newAr const.

Answer (score 0):

***Using expo-print for react native***

import * as Print from "expo-print";
import { shareAsync } from "expo-sharing";

```
htmltable = () => {
    let t = '';
    for (let i in this.state.data) {
      
      const item = this.state.data[i];
      t = t +
       `<tr>
          <td style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: center;padding: 8px">${item.p_sku}<br/></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: center;padding: 8px">${item.p_name}<br/></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: center;padding: 8px">${item.p_price}<br/></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: center;padding: 8px">${item.p_quantity}<br/></td>
<td style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: center;padding: 8px">${item.p_incl_tax_total}<br/></td>
        </tr>`
    }
    return t;
 }

in render-> use like this

 <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonstyle}
          onPress={async () => {
            const { uri } = await Print.printToFileAsync({
              html: `
              <html>
                <head>
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
                </head>
                <body style="text-align: center;">
                <h1>Order: ${Constant.ORDER_ID}</h1>
                <p>
                <strong>Order Date: ${this.state.Orderdate}</strong><br/>
                <strong>Order Total: ${this.state.OrderTotal}</strong><br/>
                <strong>Status: ${this.state.OrderStatus}</strong>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                  <th style="text-align:left"><strong>Shipping Address</strong></th>
                  <th style="text-align:left"><strong>Billing Address</strong></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Name: ${this.state.shippingname}<br/></td>
                  <td>Name: ${this.state.billingname}<br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Total : ${this.state.OrderTotal}<br/></td>
                  <td>Email: ${this.state.Billingemail}<br/></td>
                  </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Email: ${this.state.shippingemail}<br/></td>
                  <td>Ph: ${this.state.Billingphone}<br/></td>
                  </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Ph: ${this.state.shippingphone}<br/></td>
                  <td>Fax: ${this.state.Billingfax}<br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Fax: ${this.state.shippingfax}<br/></td>
                  <td>Company: ${this.state.Billingcompany}<br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Company: ${this.state.shippingcompany}<br/></td>
                  <td>Address: ${this.state.Billingaddress}<br/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Address: ${this.state.shippingaddress}<br/></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
              <th style="text-align:left"><strong>Payment</strong></th>
              <th style="text-align:left"><strong>Shipping</strong></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Payment method: ${this.state.PaymentMethod}<br/></td>
            <td>Shipping method: ${this.state.ShippingMethod}<br/></td>
          </tr>
          </table><br/><br/>
          <strong>Products: </strong><br/>
<table style="width:100%;border-collapse: collapse">
<tr>
<th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: center;padding: 8px"><strong>SKU</strong></th>
<th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: center;padding: 8px"><strong>Name</strong></th>
<th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: center;padding: 8px"><strong>Price</strong></th>
<th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: center;padding: 8px"><strong>Quantity</strong></th>
<th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: center;padding: 8px"><strong>Total</strong></th>
</tr>
${this.htmltable()}
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<table style="width:30%;border-collapse: collapse">
<tr>
<th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: left;padding: 8px"><strong>Sub-Total: ${this.state.OrderSubtotalExclTax}</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr><th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: left;padding: 8px"><strong>Shipping: ${this.state.OrderTax}</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr><th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: left;padding: 8px"><strong>Tax: ${this.state.OrderTax}</strong></th>
</tr>
<tr><th style="border: 1px solid #000000;text-align: left;padding: 8px"><strong>Order Total: ${this.state.OrderTotal}</strong></th>
</tr>
</table>
              </p>
                </body>
              </html>
              `,
            });
            // console.log("File has been saved to:", uri);
            await shareAsync(uri, { UTI: ".pdf", mimeType: "application/pdf" });
          }}
        >
          <Text
            style={{
              color: "white",
              fontWeight: "bold",
              fontSize: 16,
              textTransform: "uppercase",
              letterSpacing: 1,
            }}
          >
            Print
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31346153)